# What is the use of '?' sign in swift when push from one view controller to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I know the basic use of '?' , it is use for optional binding for variables. 
but i am not getting the mean of '?' here.

```
let obj = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(obj, animated: true)
```

I know the answer will be very basic but i am new on Swift. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case `?` was used by someone who still thinks they are writing Objective-C. Both of the `?` should be `!` to indicate developer bugs early. /snark

Answer (score 1):

It is a concept called **optional value**. I strongly suggest reading more about it in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

Basically it serves for more code safety and avoiding crashes asociated with nil exceptions. By 'asking' using the **?** you are saying - if this is not nil, perform the next thing - call the method/access variable. It could be viewed like this:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(obj, animated: true)
```

being equal to:

```
if (self.navigationController != nil) {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

or in Swift (unwrapping with if let):

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
    navController.pushViewController(obj, animated:true)
}
```

Comment: I edited your question (formatting), not voted it down.

Comment: Most likely because your question was really about the ? which is a Swift feature that you should know about and understand after reading the Swift book, which of course everyone assumes you did before starting to write code, and has nothing whatsoever to do with pushing a view controller.